# Is it possible to use Facebook limited login via OpenID Connect with Pac4J?

Tags: facebook, pac4j

I use Pac4J to authenticate users via OpenID Connect (OIDC). Note: We don't use Pac4J as a framework to do our session handling, but just as a library for OIDC. I authenticate the callback like this:

```
Optional<Credentials> credentials = client.getCredentials(context, sessionStore);
return client.getUserProfile(credentials.orElse(null), context, sessionStore)
    .map(CommonProfile.class::cast)
    .orElse(null);
```

Facebook is configured with this discovery URL: https://www.facebook.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/

Now the authentication fails, because we don't have a token endpoint. As described in this guide, the tokens are not supposed to be validated with an endpoint, but directly as JWT: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login/token/validating

How can I configure Pac4J to work with Facebook's implementation of OpenID Connect that seems to deviate from the standard? Is this possible with standard configuration options of Pac4J like `OidcConfiguration` and `OIDCProviderMetadata`? Or do we have to create custom implementations of some of the Pac4J interfaces? Or is this not possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasons why the Oidc Login via Facebook does not work regularly are the following:

- On its discovery URL (https://www.facebook.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/) Facebook does not provide you with its token endpoint (https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/oauth/access_token)
- The default scope for Facebook is not "openid email profile", but "openid email public_profile"
- Nonce has to be used for the login process
- A PKCE-method has to be selected, e.g. "plain"
- As client authentication method "client_secret_post" has to be used

We implemented the Facebook Login with a configuration page, where token endpoint, scope, useNonce, pkceMethod and client authentication method can be set manually. The data is added to the `oidcConfiguration` and thus, to the `oidcClient`.

When configured properly, the code looks like the following:

```
OidcConfiguration facebookOidcConfiguration = new OidcConfiguration();

final var providerMetadata = new OIDCProviderMetadata(
        new Issuer("https://www.facebook.com"),
        Collections.singletonList(SubjectType.PAIRWISE),
        URI.create("https://www.facebook.com/.well-known/oauth/openid/jwks/"));
providerMetadata.setTokenEndpointURI(URI.create("https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/oauth/access_token"));

//set more providerMetadata here

facebookConfiguration.setProviderMetadata(providerMetadata);
facebookConfiguration.setScope("openid email public_profile");
facebookConfiguration.setUseNonce(true);
facebookConfiguration.setPkceMethod(CodeChallengeMethod.PLAIN);
facebookConfiguration.setClientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST);

//set more configuration data here

OidcClient facebookClient = new OidcClient(facebookOidcConfiguration);
```

If you want, you can create a class `FacebookConfiguration` (inheriting from `OidcConfiguration`) to perform the described steps, but it is not required.

Answer (score 1):

By default, if you use the `OidcClient`, the token endpoint will be used.

Though, you can override any of the internal component used in the `OidcClient`. In your case, you should certainly override the `OidcAuthenticator` with a new component implementing the `Authenticator` interface: `oidcClient.setAuthenticator(myCustomOidcAuthenticator);`.

Maybe you'll also need to override the `OidcProfileCreator`: `oidcClient.setProfileCreator(myCustomOidcProfileCreator);`.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this. Hope it's fine for you, that I don't mark this accepted answer for now, because when I figure this out (or someone else does) the code can be shared here as well.

Comment: No problem. Keep us posted.